# Creating custom draw method without paintComponent()

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d

Suppose I want to create a method that has all the instructions to draw its specificities.

```
public class Martian
{
  private int eyes;
  private int legs;

  // Only arguments are the starting co-ordinates of a Graphics object
  public void draw(int x, int y)
  {
    // draw a Martian 
  }
}
```

In a separate file, I create a JFrame that needs to instantiate the object then within JFrame's `paint()` method I draw the object.

The only way I've been drawing objects is through paintComponent(), how can I create my own draw method without using that method?

Or how can I incorporate paintComponent()?

Eventually I want `paint` method to look like:

```
paint(Graphics g)
{
  // Surely more steps
  aMartian.draw(x, y);
}
```

Clearly a total noob, I would really appreciate ANY help on how to start this.

Comment: Your `draw` method should probably have a `Graphics` parameter and paint on it .

Comment: How would I use the `Graphics` object in the `draw` method without using `super.paintComponent(g)`?

Comment: From `paintComponent`, you may call `aMartian.draw(x, y, g)` .

Comment: @J.Doobie are you still facing the problem? If yes, I would like to help. As I understand for now you used JPanels paintComponent. You can actually do it differently but then you have to take care of rendering yourself a bit more because you can't just call repaint() anymore. If you're interested look up `BufferStrategy Java`. Maybe with some reading you can solve it yourself.